# How to specify the log level for hdfs command line?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I would like to have more logs when launching my hdfs commands. However, I do not know how to specify log level, or even if it is possible.

I have tested a few solutions:

- [Hadoop 2.7.0 doc on --loglevel](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#Overview)

Throws:

```
hdfs --loglevel DEBUG dfs -cat /toto

Unrecognized option: --loglevel
```

- [A cloudera post indicating the use of env var](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-use-hdfs-dfs-command-with-DEBUG-level/m-p/85654)

It has no effect.

How am I supposed to get the debug logs ? Is it even possible using Hadoop 2.6.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [look at the source of the script](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/rel/release-2.6.5/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs) to see `--loglevel` doesn't exist on that version.

You can try exporting `HADOOP_OPTS='-Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/custom-log4j.properties'` before running that script

Comment: What do I write into that file ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to log exactly, so cannot answer that. I would start with copying Hadoop's existing log4j.properties file in the config folder, and modifying that